# Can I save a changing variable into sql?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, variables

```
<script>
  var a;
  var b;
</script>
```

This is my code `var a, b` is calculated my java script, actually I am using geolocation and saving current latitude and longitude. Now I want these var to get saved in sql table.

Is this possible because I want to save the most current value of variable.

I know sql can be accessed by php but it is loaded one time at loading, but how can I send data again in php, or by any other method?

Comment: either send it using `form` or `ajax`

Comment: [5 most important things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) to tune your English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate method in which you can use "AJAX" to send the data to php and then from php to sql. Invoke that method whenever there is a change in location.here is a sample

```
function giveYourName(datatosend,urltosendto){
$.ajax({  //ajax start
        type: 'POST',
        url: urltosendto,
        data: datatosend, //data closed
        success: function(result) { //success function
              //do your thing
        } //success fumction close
      });
}
```

Comment: it is saying $ is not defined. when i removed $ it said ajax is not defined

Comment: have you included the jQuery file in your html page?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: again there is a problem ajax is showing that data is send but my php is not recieving the data why??

Comment: how are you accessing your data in php, as this is a post request you must access the data using $_POST['your_key']

Comment: what is your key in this data or datatosend

Comment: also for now i m acessing data by if ($_POST)

Comment: actually this my site [https://tripmeter.ml/dash/location/] you can access my php and java and html please tell where is the error

Comment: it is the key in which you have stored the value of the variable

Comment: this is my website directory you can access java html and php from there. plz help me  https://www.tripmeter.ml/dash/location

Comment: `function save(datatosend,urltosendto){
$.ajax({  //ajax start
        type: 'POST',
        url: urltosendto,
        data: datatosend, //data closed
        success: function(result) { //success function
              //do your thing
document.getElementById('wrongpos').innerHTML = 'data sended';
        } //success fumction close
      });
}`  this is the ajax code and i am calling it like this  `save(totaldis,'save.php');`

Comment: i need to see the datatosend variable,how are you setting it

Comment: my totaldis variable is numeric value it has values like 0.0124422

Comment: you need to send it like this {'locationValue':totaldis} and access it like $_POST['locationValue'] also if it works then vote for my post :-)

Comment: didnt worked but i stilled voted plz check my directory listing and check if there is any error plzplzplzpzlpzl https://tripmeter.ml/dash/location

Comment: or plz provide an alternative of ajax

Comment: join me on linkedin "adityaaman24" is my id,i might help you when we can talk in real time

Comment: i m not on linked in can we talk on facebook

Comment: sorry i dnt use fb